# Mongodump utility raise SocketException

Tags: mongodb, windows-server

When I try to backup my database using mongodump utility it raises the next exception:

> 2014-09-02T14:33:00.883+0400 Socket recv() errno:10055 An operation on a socket
>   could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or beca
>   use a queue was full. 127.0.0.1:27017
>
> 2014-09-02T14:33:00.883+0400 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017] assertion: 16465 recv failed while exhausting cursor

MongoDB version: 2.6.1
OS: Windows Server 32-bit

Comment: so did my answer help? any feedback on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found on MSDN it's a Windows problem

```
When you try to connect from TCP ports greater than 5000 you receive the error 'WSAENOBUFS (10055)' Print Print Email Email
```

And the solution quoted from the Windows Help Center is:

The default maximum number of ephemeral TCP ports is 5000 in the products that are included in the "Applies to" section. A new parameter has been added in these products. To increase the maximum number of ephemeral ports, follow these steps:

- Start Registry Editor.
- Locate the following subkey in the registry, and then click Parameters:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
- On the Edit menu, click New, and then add the following registry entry:

> Value Name: MaxUserPort
>
> Value Type: DWORD
>
> Value data: 65534
>
> Valid Range: 5000-65534 (decimal)
>
> Default: 0x1388 (5000 decimal)

- Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

You can find more details about the issue and the detailed description of the solution by going to the [Windows Support Center](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271/en)

Comment: Perhaps, rather than brutally increasing the amount of system resources that a service can use, it would be a good idea to first find out why it is using so many system resources in the first place, for example by looking at open connections with `netstat -bano` or a similar tool.

Comment: @FlorianWinter thanks for the tips, at that point it was a known limitation, for sure it's been improved since that time, I'll edit the answer and add the suggested alternative

Comment: No worries. I came across this when I was dealing with an issue of some runaway service flooding MongoDB with connections. Where this is a normal condition, your answer sure may be helpful.

Comment: This answer seems to only apply to Windows up to Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port. You can easily see if it applies by running `netstat -bano` to see if clients use ports < 5000 or ports in the IANA range